# How do I put the code `cons[A;B]` in a repl, run it, and see the output `(A . B)`?

Tags: lisp, metalanguage

I found a [LISP 1.5 Manual](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/LISP/book/LISP%201.5%20Programmers%20Manual.pdf) with some code in it.

This one is from Section 1.2

```erlang
Examples

    cons[A;B]=(A . B)
```

From reading through the manual it looks like the function `cons` is taking two atoms as input arguments, `A` and `B`, and outputting an S-expression, `(A . B)`.

Question:

How do I put the code `cons[A;B]` in a repl, run it, and see the output `(A . B)`?

I'm expecting to do something like:

```erlang
~ $ lisp1.5
> cons[A;B]
=> (A . B)
```

For example, if I went to https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/ and saw some code, I would copy it, type `irb` into my shell and paste it.

[image]

```erlang
~ $ irb
irb(main):001:0> puts "Hello World!"
Hello World!
=> nil
```

Comment: You mean: `(cons 'A 'B)`?

Comment: Note that `cons[A;B]` is written in the so-called Metalanguage, not in Lisp, which is instead written as S-Expressions (like `(cons 'A 'B)`). This is explained later in the manual. So you should get a lisp (Scheme, Common Lisp, etc.) interpreter/compiler and use S-Expressions.

Comment: What you are describing is M-expressions which was a proposed syntax for Lisp which was never implemented.  See, for instance [the Wikipedia entry for them](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-expression).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section 1.2 of the manual explains that this is only a notation, used to help readers distinguish between functions and S-expressions (emphasis mine).

> We shall introduce some elementary functions of S-expressions. **To distinguish
>   the functions from the S-expressions themselves**, we shall write function names in
>   I lower case letters, since atomic symbols consist of only upper case letters. Furthermore,
>   the arguments of functions will be grouped in square brackets rather than
>   parentheses. As a separator or punctuation mark we shall use the semicolon.

It is followed by an example:

```
cons[A ; B] = (A . B)
```

The manual introduces Lisp, its evaluation model, the compiler, etc. 
The above is the mathematical definition of `cons`, where `A` and `B` are metavariables: for all values `A` and `B`, the application of `cons` on `A` and `B` is a cons-cell where the CAR part is `A` and the CDR part `B`. If someone developed a denotational semantics to express Ruby's evaluation model, you would have the same kind of definitions. You can convert this notation if you want, i.e. you write `(cons 1 2)` to test it concretely. But the 1.5 manual is arguably not the best starting point for learning Common Lisp, as standardized since 1994. You could try the following ones, instead:

- [Practical Common Lisp](http://gigamonkeys.com/book/), Peter Seibel
- [Paradigms of Artificial Intelligence Programming](https://github.com/norvig/paip-lisp), Peter Norvig

Please consult [Cliki](https://cliki.net/Getting%20Started), the Common Lisp wiki.